# Grails: how to log wslite SOAP messages?

Tags: grails, logging, soap

We are using wslite SOAP client plugin thusly:

```
def response = client.send(SOAPAction: someAction)    {
    body {
        Something('xmlns': xmlns, 'xmlns:i': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")     {
            moreStuff(hello)
        }
    }
}
```

We want to log the SOAP request and response.  Setting up SSL proxies is possible in some cases, but not on production - we need to be able to write the request/response to a log file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet (assuming `log` is connected, f.e. via @Slf4j annotattion of your class):

```
log.debug("Sent: ${response?.httpRequest?.contentAsString}") 
log.debug("Got: ${response?.httpResponse?.contentAsString}")
```